# Why TabIndex property of any element in WPF is 2147483647?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

In `WPF`application by default `TabIndex = 2147483647` for any element. 
Why it is `2147483647`? 
Why not any other number? 
Am I missing something? 
I'm just interested.

Comment: The number 2147483647 is the maximum value for a 32-bit signed integer. It is also the eighth Mersenne prime: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This number is MaxInt, or 2^31 - 1 (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647))

As you cannot possibly choose a higher number for your own tab indices, this ensures that new controls never alter an existing tab order, if one has been manually specified.

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing here but I can think of one reason.

Let's say you already have three controls on your form, with TabIndices 1, 2 and 3. Now if you add a fourth control underneath your others, it won't initially break your Tab order. While if the index would have been 0 or 1, your tab order would have been messed up and you would be forced to change the index immediately.

Another reason could be that this way you could first add all your controls and set up the tab order later. You would start by making your first control 0, the second 1, etc. If all controls would already be 0, you would have a lot of work before you could actually see any results.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes your answer is helpful. But you said that you are just guessing. Anyway thanks to you